# Error upgrading nginx in Stretch

Tags: debian, apt, sysvinit, monit

In the last Debian Stretch routing security updates I had a problem. When trying install the security upgrades, and consequently upgrading `nginx`, I got the following error bellow.

I have tried running `apt-get upgrade`again, or `apt-get install` with any of the involved packages, but nothing seems to work.

What to do?

```
$ apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up libnginx-mod-stream (1.10.2-2) ...
nginx: [alert] kill(1433, 1) failed (3: No such process)
dpkg: error processing package libnginx-mod-stream (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libnginx-mod-http-echo (1.10.2-2) ...
nginx: [alert] kill(1433, 1) failed (3: No such process)
dpkg: error processing package libnginx-mod-http-echo (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx-full:
 nginx-full depends on libnginx-mod-http-echo (= 1.10.2-2); however:
  Package libnginx-mod-http-echo is not configured yet.
 nginx-full depends on libnginx-mod-stream (= 1.10.2-2); however:
  Package libnginx-mod-stream is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nginx-full (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair (1.10.2-2) ...
nginx: [alert] kill(1433, 1) failed (3: No such process)
dpkg: error processing package libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libnginx-mod-http-geoip (1.10.2-2) ...
nginx: [alert] kill(1433, 1) failed (3: No such process)
dpkg: error processing package libnginx-mod-http-geoip (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
 nginx depends on nginx-full (<< 1.10.2-2.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.10.2-2.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.10.2-2.1~); however:
  Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.
 nginx depends on nginx-full (>= 1.10.2-2) | nginx-light (>= 1.10.2-2) | nginx-extras (>= 1.10.2-2); however:
  Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libnginx-mod-stream
 libnginx-mod-http-echo
 nginx-full
 libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair
 libnginx-mod-http-geoip
 nginx
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, analysing the problem, and looking at the post install scripts, the problem was determined. When installing/upgrading any of those `nginx` components, every single one of those packages, try to restart `nginx` and check for the success of the operation.

So, in our update operations, we have to start stopping `monit` before doing the maintenance security updates/upgrades cycle, for it not to start `nginx` midway the process of `apt-get upgrade`.

The fix was ultimately, and in order:

- stopping `monit`;
- doing a `(p)kill -9` to the `nginx` processes (strangely the stop seemed to be no longer effective)
- doing a `service start nginx`
- and finally doing again `apt-get upgrade` again.
- Finally, at the end of a successful upgrade doing `service monit start`.

This time without `monit` getting in the way, the `upgrade` was effective.

At the end of the day, the lesson is to modify our standard upgrade procedures, and change our Ansible playbook to stop or ideally suspend `monit` before the security updates process.

Comment: The post-installation and pre-deinstallation scripts for nginx-full run `invoke-rc.d` with `start` and `stop` at various points.  So if you can find a way to connect monit up to `invoke-rc.d` things should happen automatically for you.

Comment: @JdeBP thxs for idea, I will investigate that.